# Excel Custom Data Validation

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have to restrict some invalid data in a Excel Column.

Below is Validation Criteria:

- Should be a numeric Number
- Size/Length should be equals to 9

Ex : valid:602005514, invalid:were,43456 etc.

I have created a Custom Data Validation using below function.

```
=AND(LEN(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$","")))=9,
     ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$","")))) 
 //here i have to get cell name dynamically. so, i have used ADDRESS function
```

But its not working as expected. It is not allowing any value in cell.
I guess it might be because of LEN function circular reference.

I have tried many ways, but not able to solve it. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to resort to `INDIRECT` etc, in you formula just refer to top left cell in the range you are applying the validation.to.  Excel will adjust for the othger cells in the range.  When entering cell references don't use absolute references, ie no `$`'s

Eg select a range starting at cell A1, and set data validation formula to

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A1),LEN(A1)=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple validation .. checking Cell D13 ..

```
=IF(LEN(D13)=9,IF(ISNUMBER(D13),"yes","no"),"no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1>99999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in the cell:

```
=IF(TRIM(A3)=A3,TRUE,FALSE)
```